# Amavis + Monit: "Error receiving data from the mailserver -- Resource temporarily unavailable "

Tags: linux, monit, amavis

Good morning folks,

I'm often getting these monit alerts, about once or twice a day:

```
Connection failed Service amavisd

Date: Wed, 20 Jul 2022 09:04:58
Action: restart
Host: (hidden).com
Description: failed protocol test [SMTP] at [localhost]:10024 [TCP/IP] -- Error receiving data from the mailserver -- Resource temporarily unavailable

Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

and then shortly after about 20 seconds it's back running, with this email alert:

```
Connection succeeded Service amavisd

Date: Wed, 20 Jul 2022 09:07:03
Action: alert
Host: (hidden).com
Description: connection succeeded to [localhost]:10024 [TCP/IP]

Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

A bit too much noise for me for already getting many emails every day. Can this configuration be improved, not to alert me until a couple of retries or so? Or the other way around, investigate what error from the mail server has been returned?

Here is the current Monit configuration:

```
check process amavisd with pidfile /var/run/amavis/amavisd.pid
 group mail
 start program = "/etc/init.d/amavis start"
 stop  program = "/etc/init.d/amavis stop"
 if failed port 10024 protocol smtp then restart
 if 3 restarts within 3 cycles then alert
 if 6 restarts within 6 cycles then timeout
 depends on amavisd_bin
 depends on amavisd_rc

check file amavisd_bin with path /usr/sbin/amavisd-new
 group mail
 if failed checksum then unmonitor
 if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
 if failed uid root then unmonitor
 if failed gid root then unmonitor

check file amavisd_rc with path /etc/init.d/amavis
 group mail
 if failed checksum then unmonitor
 if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
 if failed uid root then unmonitor
 if failed gid root then unmonitor
```

Can you spot the issue?

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 0):

In Monit, in your rules, you can configure it to avoid false-positive or after several failure such as

```
if failed port 10024 for 3 times within 5 cycles then alert
```

More detail in the documentation at https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FAULT-TOLERANCE

Comment: Thanks. Well, I already have that in my config, but it is still happening. I've updated my original post with my existing Monit config. Can you spot the issue?

Comment: The issue is the way to restart, see "if failed port 10024 protocol smtp then restart" and replace it by something like "if failed port 10024 protocol smtp for 3 times within 5 cycles then restart". Sometimes it is useful to test the port only, without the "protocol smtp".